# Git/Egit configs

Tags: linux, eclipse, git, egit

I am trying to migrate to git and would like to stay inside my familiar IDE (Eclipse), and apparently Egit is the plugin to use.

A few questions:

1. Does Egit require `git`? Meaning, do I need to first install `git` on my machine, *prior* to installing the Egit plugin?; and
2. If the answer to #1 above is "yes", and I do need to first install `git`, then after I install git, are there any system-level configurations, or `git` commands (to be ran from the shell) that I need to perform *before* I install Egit? **Note** I do plan on using a private repo on GitHub which I believe uses SSL keys...if that changes the answer to this question at all...

Also I'm on Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 - just fyi in case there are linux-specific settings, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, EGit does not require Git as it is based [JGit](http://eclipse.org/jgit/), which is a pure Java implementation of Git.